# Regex that recognizes everything except text between quotes?

Tags: php, regex

I need to make a regex that recognizes everything except text between quotes.
Here is an example:

```
my_var == "Hello world!"
```

I want to get `my_var` but not `Hello world!`.

I tried `(?<!\")([A-Za-z0-9]+)` but it didn't work.

Comment: This post will soon receive an incredible number of downvotes...

Comment: When you say "everything", do you mean "everything everything" or just "everything"?

Comment: @Pappa I would translate it to the equivalent of a wife saying "Nothing's wrong"

Comment: I mean characters in [A-Za-z0-9\-_\.]

Comment: You can try replacing text with quotes instead... [Example](http://regex101.com/r/wH7oL1)

Comment: @Louis I did not downvote you but I am positive that the downvotes came from people with much more rep points than me. Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/about and specifically check out the "`Get answers to practical, detailed questions`" section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would of took the time to [`google`](https://www.google.com/) or search [`stackoverflow`](http://www.stackoverflow.com), you would find answers to this question that have already been answered by not only me, but many other users out there.

[`@Pappa's`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1343420/pappa) answer using a *`negative lookbehind`* will only match a simple test case and not everything in a string that is **not enclosed** by quotes. I would suffice for a *`negative lookahead`* in this case, if you're wanting to match all word characters in any given data.

```
/[\w.-]+(?![^"]*"(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/hD4hU5)

Example:

```
<?php

$text = <<<T
my_var == "Hello world!" foo /(^*#&^$ 
"hello" foobar "hello" FOO "hello" baz
Hi foo, I said "hello" $&@^$(@$)@$&*@(*$&
T;

preg_match_all('/[\w.-]+(?![^"]*"(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => my_var
            [1] => foo
            [2] => foobar
            [3] => FOO
            [4] => baz
            [5] => Hi
            [6] => foo
            [7] => I
            [8] => said
        )
)
```

Comment: Hi hwnd, the solution you posted is definitely better than the one I initially posted, but I just noticed that it fails to match as expected if there are an odd number of quotes. I suppose that's out of the scope of the question though.

Comment: Yea, OP didn't state whether he had nested quotes or what not. That is a whole different ballgame.

Answer (score 2):

You have an accepted answer but I am still submitting once since I believe this answer is better in capturing more edge cases:

```
$s = 'my_var == "Hello world!" foo';
if (preg_match_all('/[\w.-]+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/', $s, $arr))
   print_r($arr[0]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => my_var
    [1] => foo
)
```

This works by using a lookahead to make sure there are even # of double quotes are followed (requires balanced double quotes and no escaping).

Comment: You were a minute too slow. =) Positive lookahead will work in this case too.

Comment: I was waiting for someone to comment what if input is something like: `'my_var == "Hello it\"s a world!" foo'` :P

Comment: Some users do not think outside the box on realistic cases before they ask a specific question on a topic. :)

Answer (score 1):

As much as I'll regret getting downvoted for answering this, I was intrigued, so did it anyway.

```
(?<![" a-zA-Z])([A-Za-z0-9\-_\.]+)
```

Comment: It works ! Thank you and sorry for my poor question :( It was the first one .. I swear I'll do better next time !

Comment: @Pappa, this works for the beginning of the line and if his test string is simple like that, but won't work for all cases. See here.. http://regex101.com/r/sP4rG6

Comment: Good point. I didn't really put too much effort into it, just a simple solution. There are some great answers on this page.

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution hasn't been mentioned (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/tU7yO9)):

```
"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|[\w.-]+
```

**Reference**

[How to match pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)